# How does WebView.loadurl work behind the scenes?

Tags: java, android, webview

I am new to android development. Figured out that the `loadUrl` function from `WebView.java` has the following definition:

```
public void loadUrl(String url) {
        checkThread();
        mProvider.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

where `mProvider` is just an instance of interface WebViewProvider. Obviously the function does not do anything inside the interface itself.

Now how does calling this function actually loads the url when it actually  does nothing anywhere in the above mentioned places.

is it actually a general programming concept that I don't understand. Can you please explain?

Comment: `mProvider` is a **realization** of `WebViewProvider` interface. The work will be done by mProvider inside of `public void loadUrl(String url);` method. Android just hides details of the method implementation in sources

Comment: where can I find the code of this thing?

Comment: I am not sure but may be [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/webview/+/lollipop-release/chromium/java/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewChromium.java)